# How can I use related Filters in a List component?

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to use a kind of "related filters" in a `<List>` component inside my app.
The idea is similar to a situation that you have a filter with country names and after you choose one, the second filter, will have the cities names related to the country in the first filter.

I made a custom component like this:

```js
const CityFilter = props => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Country {...props} />
      <FormDataConsumer>
        {({ formData, ...rest }) => (
         <SelectInput 
           {...props} 
           label="City" 
           source="cityId" 
           optionText="name" 
           optionValue="id"
           choices={getCitiesfor(formData.countryId)}
           parse={(v) => parseInt(v)}
           {...rest}
         />
       )}
      </FormDataConsumer>
    </Fragment>);
};
```

and it works good but the issue is that after you close the filter components the `<List>` still remains filtered.
So, there're any other way to do that? or how can i do to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, would you kindly include how you are exactly the above component in a `<List>`?